# Getting an Interstitial Ad to Display from a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, interstitial

i've been searching for hours now, and i can't get a simple interstitial ad to display.  the layout is within a fragment and i'm sure that's part of the problem, but i can't find a work around.  any help is greatly appreciated - most of what i see is displaying the ad within an activity.

I want the interstitial to appear before the user clicks on a button in an app. i'm sure the issue is with the (this) but I can't find anything.

```
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("example ad unit");

    mapFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(Constants.MAPS_INTENT_URI));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes the problem is with the `this`. Since you are calling it in a Fragment, it won't work. Because this is the constructor from the docs:

[public InterstitialAd (Context context)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd.html#public-constructors)

The constructor requires the context. So change your code like this:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getContext());
```

Comment: If you're targeting < API 23, you'd want to use `getActivity()` rather than `getContext()`.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid NullPointerException, you can use requireContext()

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(requireContext());
```

Comment: requireContext() still giving crash